# Searching in JSON for specific value using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to filter my JSON object by a specific property value set to `Log: true`

If an object has this property set to false, I want to filter it out. Here is an example of the JSON structure:

```
$scope.Main =
    { 
          "MyBook" :  
          {
            "Title": "The Road",
            "Type" : "Text",
            "Log" : false
          },
          "MyCat":
          {
            "Name" :  "Penny",
            "Type" :  "Pet",
            "Log" : true            
          },
          "Car":
          {
            "Make" :  "Toyota",
            "Model" : "Camry",
            "Type" :  "Vehicle",
            "Log" : false     
          }
    }
```

As you can see, the objects themselves are not similar, but they all contains a log property.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Is this within an ng-repeat or something? The solution is to use Filters, but we need more details. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: This would happen in a function in a controller Brandon.

Answer (score 1):

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9AAxE/1/)**

This is how I would filtered an object while searching for a **property** value equals **true**

```
var sampleObj = {/* you sample object*/}; 

var filtered = Object.keys(sampleObj).reduce(function(arr,prop){
    if(Object.keys(sampleObj[prop])
        .filter(function (p) {return p === "Log";})){
            if(sampleObj[prop].Log==true){
                arr.push(sampleObj[prop]);
            }

    }
    return arr;
},[]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Since you are using angular probably you would want to use a custom filter instead:

Something close to:

**custom filter**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(sampleObj, param1) {
        return Object.keys(sampleObj).reduce(function(arr,prop){
            if(Object.keys(sampleObj[prop])
                .filter(function (p) {return p === "Log";})){
                if(sampleObj[prop].Log==param1){
                    arr.push(sampleObj[prop]);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        },[]);
    };
});
```

and in your **html**

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in sampleObj | myFilter: true">
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the [underscorejs library](http://underscorejs.org).

you can use some of their functions like `_.filter` and `_.has` to filter the list.

here's an example of how i would try to implement that object:

```
var filtered = _.filter($scope.Main, function(obj) {
    return _.has(obj, "Log") && obj.Log;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom Angular filter:

```
.filter('filterLog', function(){
  return function(items){
    for (var item in items) {
      if (items[item].Log === false) delete items[item];
    }
    return items;
  }
})
```

Then, in your view, you could output the filtered list like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Main | filterLog">{{value}}</li>
```

If you need to use it in a controller, you could:

```
$scope.filtered = $filter('filterLog')($scope.Main);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QjLoYBdLn20Fbs3VcSk6?p=preview)